# how fetch elements of array using request parameter in specified ranges

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, request

I have a folder in which there are 12 files, in php i am send two request parameters are:

```
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
```

means if i write there from 1 to 9, then i'll get all files which is in array as:

```
 $path = 'example/'
    $files = scandir($path);

    $fi = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fi[] = $file; --> array
    }
```

all file ranges which i am specified using request parameters are display files using through echo or explode, i am trying this, if there is more efficient way then please enlighten on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$fi = array_slice($files, $from, $to - $from);
```

If `$_REQUEST[from]` and `[to]` are 1-indexed, simply substract 1 from both:

```
$from = $_REQUEST['from'] - 1;
$to = $_REQUEST['to'] - 1
```

Comment: I am done, but when i am put a foreach loop on array variable to fetch all files and explode it, i get an error of array to sting? without explode how could i display all values

Comment: Here i am trying like if my data files are stored on external storage, and i am running my script on another server, then i have to use these files without using statically like: $arr = array('url'=>"http://example.com/file/one.txt");